Getting an "Instances of abstract classes cannot be created" exception when receiving state machine initial message
I have been trying to understand an error that MassTransit has been throwing without success. I created a SAGA using Azure Service Bus. When I Start my project everything is initialized fine. But as soon as I receive the event that is supposed to start my state machine I get the following error:
System.InvalidOperationException: Instances of abstract classes cannot be created.
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance(IServiceProvider provider, Type instanceType, Object[] parameters)
     at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetServiceOrCreateInstance[T](IServiceProvider provider)
     at MassTransit.DependencyInjection.CreatedConsumeScopeContext`1.GetService[T]() in /_/src/MassTransit/DependencyInjection/DependencyInjection/CreatedConsumeScopeContext.cs:line 57
     at MassTransit.Middleware.OutboxConsumeFilter`2.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next)
     at MassTransit.Middleware.OutboxConsumeFilter`2.Send(ConsumeContext`1 context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/OutboxConsumeFilter.cs:line 41
     at MassTransit.Middleware.RedeliveryRetryFilter`2.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RedeliveryRetryFilter.cs:line 46
     at MassTransit.Middleware.RedeliveryRetryFilter`2.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RedeliveryRetryFilter.cs:line 70
     at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 47
     at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 118
     at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 47
     at MassTransit.Middleware.RetryFilter`1.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RetryFilter.cs:line 118
     at MassTransit.Middleware.RedeliveryRetryFilter`2.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RedeliveryRetryFilter.cs:line 46
     at MassTransit.Middleware.RedeliveryRetryFilter`2.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RedeliveryRetryFilter.cs:line 70
     at MassTransit.Middleware.InMemoryOutboxFilter`2.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/InMemoryOutboxFilter.cs:line 35
     at MassTransit.Middleware.InMemoryOutboxFilter`2.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/InMemoryOutboxFilter.cs:line 45
     at MassTransit.Middleware.TeeFilter`1.<>c__DisplayClass5_0.<<Send>g__SendAsync|1>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/TeeFilter.cs:line 40
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at MassTransit.Middleware.ConsumeContextOutputMessageTypeFilter`1.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, ConsumeContext`1 pipeContext) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/ConsumeContextOutputMessageTypeFilter.cs:line 76
     at MassTransit.Middleware.ConsumeContextOutputMessageTypeFilter`1.SendToOutput(IPipe`1 next, ConsumeContext`1 pipeContext) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/ConsumeContextOutputMessageTypeFilter.cs:line 108
     at MassTransit.Middleware.ConsumeContextMessageTypeFilter.<>c__DisplayClass8_0.<<Send>g__SendAsync|0>d.MoveNext() in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/MessageTypeFilter.cs:line 76
  --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
     at MassTransit.Middleware.DeserializeFilter.Send(ReceiveContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/DeserializeFilter.cs:line 40
     at MassTransit.Middleware.RescueFilter`2.MassTransit.IFilter<TContext>.Send(TContext context, IPipe`1 next) in /_/src/MassTransit/Middleware/RescueFilter.cs:line 43

Here is my MassTransit Bus Conguration
public void Configure(IBusRegistrationConfigurator options)
{
 Debug.WriteLine($"MassTransit.Startup: Configuring Azure Service Bus with MassTransit");

 options.AddServiceBusMessageScheduler();

 options.AddSagaStateMachine<InvitationStateMachine, InvitationSate>(typeof(InvitationStateDefinition))
         .RedisRepository(r =>
         {
             r.DatabaseConfiguration(_redisConnectionString);

             r.KeyPrefix = nameof(InvitationStateMachine);

             // Optional, the default is 30 seconds
             r.LockTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(90);
         });

 options.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
 {
     cfg.Host(_serviceBusConnectionString);
     cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();

     ////cfg.UseInMemoryOutbox(context);
     ////cfg.UseDelayedRedelivery(ScheduledRetryConfigurator.Get());
     ////cfg.UseMessageRetry(ImmediateRetryConfigurator.Get());

     // required to pick up the consumers and auto-detected endpoints for publishers
     cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
 });
}

Here is my state Machine :
public class InvitationStateMachine : MassTransitStateMachine<InvitationSate>
{

    private readonly ILogger<InvitationStateMachine> _logger;
    private readonly IHubContext<InvitationHub> _hubContext;


    public InvitationStateMachine(ILogger<InvitationStateMachine> logger, IHubContext<InvitationHub> hubContext)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        DefineBehavior();
    }

    public State InProgress { get; }

    public State Completed { get; }

    public State Errored { get; }

    public Event<InitiateLegacyUsersInviteRequest> InitiateLegacyUsersInviteEvent { get; }

    public Event<ErrorInvitationRequest> ErrorInvitationEvent { get; }

    public Event<CompleteLegacyUserInviteRequest> CompleteLegacyUserInviteEvent { get; }

    public Event<DismissLegacyUserInviteRequest> DismissInvitationEvent { get; }

    public Schedule<InvitationSate, DismissLegacyUserInviteRequest> DismissInvitationSchedule { get; }

    private void DefineBehavior()
    {
        InstanceState(x => x.CurrentState);

        Event(() => InitiateLegacyUsersInviteEvent, x => x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId));
        Event(() => ErrorInvitationEvent, x => x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId));
        Event(() => CompleteLegacyUserInviteEvent, x => x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId));
        Event(() => DismissInvitationEvent, x => x.CorrelateById(context => context.Message.CorrelationId));
        Schedule(() => DismissInvitationSchedule, x => x.DismissScheduleId, x => x.Delay = TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

        InitialBehavior();

        InProgressBehavior();

        CompletedBehavior();

        ErrorBehavior();

        SetCompletedWhenFinalized();
    }
private void InitialBehavior() => Initially(
            When(InitiateLegacyUsersInviteEvent)
            .Then(x =>
            {
                x.Saga.TenantId = x.Message.TenantId;
                x.Saga.ClientConnectionId = x.Message.ClientConnectionId;
            })
            .Then(x =>
            {
                _logger.LogInformation(
                    "User Invitation State Machine started with CorrelationId: '{CorrelationId}', TenantId: '{TenantId}' for ClientConnectionId: '{ClientConnectionId}' ",
                    x.Message.CorrelationId,
                    x.Message.TenantId,
                    x.Message.ClientConnectionId);
            })
            .Schedule(
                DismissInvitationSchedule,
                context => new DismissLegacyUserInviteRequest
                {
                    CorrelationId = context.Message.CorrelationId,
                    TenantId = context.Message.TenantId
                })
            .PublishAsync(context =>
            {
                ProcessLegacyUsersInviteRequest request = new(
                    context.Message.CorrelationId,
                    context.Message.Invitees,
                    context.Message.BaseAddress,
                    context.Message.TenantId,
                    context.Message.InvitingUserId);
                return context.Init<ProcessLegacyUsersInviteRequest>(request);
            })
            .TransitionTo(InProgress),
            Ignore(CompleteLegacyUserInviteEvent),
            Ignore(DismissInvitationEvent),
            Ignore(ErrorInvitationEvent));
}

Here is the saga definition:
public class InvitationStateDefinition : SagaDefinition<InvitationSate>
{
    protected override void ConfigureSaga(IReceiveEndpointConfigurator endpointConfigurator, ISagaConfigurator<InvitationSate> sagaConfigurator, IRegistrationContext context)
    {
        endpointConfigurator.UseInMemoryInboxOutbox(context);
        endpointConfigurator.UseMessageRetry(ImmediateRetryConfigurator.Get());
        endpointConfigurator.UseScheduledRedelivery(ScheduledRetryConfigurator.Get());

        if (endpointConfigurator is IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator sbc)
        {
            sbc.RequiresSession = true;
        }
    }
}

My state machine Instance:
public class InvitationSate : SagaStateMachineInstance, ISagaVersion
{
    public Guid? DismissScheduleId { get; set; }

    public Guid UserId { get; set; }

    public Guid CorrelationId { get; set; }

    public Guid TenantId { get; set; }

    public int Version { get; set; }

    public string? ClientConnectionId { get; set; }

    public string CurrentState { get; set; }

}

I'm calling the initiating the state machine from a different project this way:
InitiateLegacyUsersInviteRequest busRequest = new(
    correlationId,
    request.Invitees ?? [],
    baseAddress,
    Guid.Parse(tenantId, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture),
    request.ConnectionId ?? string.Empty,
    adminApiUserId);
////ProcessLegacyUsersInviteRequest testReq = new(correlationId, request.Invitees ?? [], baseAddress, Guid.Parse(tenantId, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture), adminApiUserId);
await busControl.Publish(busRequest, cancellationToken);

with busControl being an IBusControl type.
The application initiating the Saga is configured like this:
public void Configure(IBusRegistrationConfigurator options)
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"MassTransit.Startup: Configuring Azure Service Bus with MassTransit");

    options.AddServiceBusMessageScheduler();

    options.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, cfg) =>
    {
        cfg.Host(_serviceBusConnectionString);
        cfg.UseServiceBusMessageScheduler();

        cfg.UseDelayedRedelivery(ScheduledRetryConfigurator.Get());
        cfg.UseMessageRetry(ImmediateRetryConfigurator.Get());

        cfg.Send<InitiateLegacyUsersInviteRequest>(opts =>
            opts.UseSessionIdFormatter(context => context.Message.CorrelationId.Equals(Guid.Empty) ? ApiConstants.MassTransitEntityName : context.Message.CorrelationId.ToString()));

        // required to pick up the consumers and auto-detected endpoints for publishers
        cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
    });
}

I'm not sure what can be the problem. I had similar configuration using MassTransit 7.1.8 and it was working fine.
Please help :'(
I have tried downgrading to Mass Transit 8.2.2 but I'm still getting the same error. I also tried not using Redis and try Cosmos instead with no success.
If I publish a message for my consumer ( I did not include the code for it) the message is consumed with no problem. It's only when I try to start the state machine that I get the error.

Stack Overflow is not a support channel for MassTransit. If you can reproduce the problem in a standalone repository on GitHub, create a discussion on GitHub with that repository. Otherwise, you'll need to go through support.

Thank you for your reply. I will create a repository on GitHub with my scenario

I’m voting to close this question because it's a support question related to MassTransit, and not a general question suitable for the overall SO audience. It was also asked and answered here: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/discussions/5430
